# Probability of sequence with binary data

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say I have n balls, x blue and (n-x) red. If I draw the balls randomly one at a time without replacement, what is the probability of having a series of k blue balls drawn in a row?

I am looking for an exact-solution alternative to my computational solution listed below on SO to aid in simulating a golf event.
x-posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483390/probability-of-sequence-with-binary-data

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Do you replace your balls after you picked them? also add some details and attempts please

Comment: One sequence with k blue balls in a row is $\underbrace{b...b}_{k}\underbrace{r...r}_{n-k}  $. Now we can replace the sub-sequence  $\underbrace{b...b}_{k}$ by one big Element B.

$${B}\underbrace{r...r}_{n-k}  $$

This sequence can be arranged in $n-k+1$ ways. This are the number of favorable outcomes. Comprehensible so far?

Comment: @callculus42 thanks! and denominator is just number of all possible permutations n!/(x!*(n-x)!).

Comment: @callculus42 I see where you're going. But just out of curiosity, what is the flaw in arguing that there are $x \choose{k}$ ways to choose a $k$-length block of blue balls (assuming $x \geq k$), and then $(n-k)!$ ways to permute the remaining balls not in the block. Thus, a final probability of $\frac{{x\choose{k}}(n-1)!}{n!}$?

Comment: Yeah, I'm also realizing it doesn't take into effect the number of blue balls. I think this holds when k=x and no for values of x>k.

Comment: @JoshSandoval Yes, that's right.